# How can I calculate columns when using grouping sets

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query that is giving me results using grouping sets:

```
 Select
       store,
       product,
       FiscalMonth,
       FIscalYear,
       SUM(Amount),
       CASE WHEN FiscalMonth IS NULL THEN SUM(Amount) ELSE NULL END AS Total
 From Sales
 Group by store, product, 
        Grouping Sets(
                      (FiscalYear, FiscalMonth, product),
                      (FiscalYear, product)
                     )
```

Which gives me a nice set of results grouped by FiscalMonth and FiscalYear:

```
Store      Product     FiscalMonth      FiscalYear     Amount       Total
1          123         NULL             2007           23.00        452.00
1          123         1/1/2007         2007           55.00        NULL
1          123         1/2/2007         2007           11.00        NULL
1          123         2/1/2007         2007           28.00        NULL
1          123         NULL             2008           28.00        552.00
1          123         3/1/2008         2008           99.00        NULL
1          123         4/1/2008         2008           36.00        NULL
1          123         4/2/2008         2008           55.00        NULL
1          123         4/3/2008         2008           89.00        NULL
```

The problem I'm having is how can I create a column that compares Fiscal 2007 and Fiscal 2008, i would like an additional column "Diff" that=-100 (452-552)

I've tried creating some different columns with CASE statements, but it seem ultimately, each row only knows about Monthly Sum and Yearly sum of the current date, I can't seem to jump around to get previous years sum.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Column `SUM(Amount)` in the posted query doesn't have an alias but its relative position matches that of the `Amount` column in the posted output, so I'm assuming the two are the same column. However, why do `Amount`and `Total` differ on rows where `FiscalMonth` is NULL? Based on the query, I would expect them to be equal (on those rows), so... I'm confused. That, to a degree, is related to another question, which is more to the point of your problem: on which row should `Diff` be -100? Should it be a new row, perhaps? Or do you want it to be -100 across all the rows currently being produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query below can do what you want, you just have check for datatypes in ***convert*** (as i don't know which datatypes you are using so i assumed varchar(20) as year).
I get the previous year total in isNUll() and subtract it from current total and then multplied the result with -100.

```
Select
   store,
   product,
   FiscalMonth,
   FIscalYear,
   SUM(Amount),
   (-100 * ((ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM sales WHERE FiscalYear = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),(CONVERT(INT, s.FiscalYear) - 1)) AND FiscalMonth IS NULL Group by FIscalYear),0) -  
 CASE WHEN FiscalMonth IS NULL THEN SUM(Amount) ELSE NULL END
 ))) as Diff

From Sales
Group by store, product, 
    Grouping Sets(
                  (FiscalYear, FiscalMonth, product),
                  (FiscalYear, product)
                 )
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping to not have to scan the data again doing another SELECT, but it appears that's the only way to do it.  Fortunately the performance hit wasn't that bad. I ended up implementing a form of what you have here.  Thanks!